# How much fertilizer should I supply my multifarm with?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm trying to work out the rate at which my multifarm will consume fertilizer. The rate is listed as [30mU on the Forestry wiki](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=farms:programming), but it doesn't say over what period this amount is consumed.

If I am setting up a redpower timer to push an apatite to my crafting table (i.e. making 8 fertilizer), how often should I set it to go off to maintain balance?

Comment: I believe those numbers are "per operation", which may not be very helpful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The 30mU value you referenced is the amount consumed per operation. The frequency of operations is entirely dependent on the growth rate of your selected crop(s). The growth of crops is, by its very nature, inconsistent and randomized. Although it might be possible to work out a close "average" value, it is going to be far more accurate to build a system that supplies fertilizer as it is needed, rather than blindly sending it every x seconds. This could be accomplished with routers, or even just tubes and transposers.